# Dealing with Java Expression Language on a page

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, el

I am working on the frontend of a project that gives me Java Expression Language tags to work with. In one instance I need to see if it is returning an array or just one bit of data and I don't know how to work with it.

Example:

The page has

```
<p>${WebAppContext.buildings[0].location.name}</p>
```

which will output something like:

```
<p>Acme</p>
```

Problem is I need to output more if there is more in that buildings bit:

Something like (in pseudocode):

```
if isArray(${WebAppContext.buildings}){
 foreach(${WebAppContext.buildings} as foo){
    //iterate over whatever is in the array
}
}
```

so I can output something like:

```
<p>${WebAppContext.buildings[0].location.name}</p>
<p>${WebAppContext.buildings[1].location.name}</p>
```

I asked the Java people responsible for generating this code and they said "Dunnokindofbusyrightnowbuhbye." so I'm hoping you folks will have some insight.

Beyond sticking the code in the page I don't have a clue how to work with this Java Expression Language (I even had to look it up to see what the heck it is called). So any advice/resources would be helpful.

---

**EDIT:**

I've tried the following and am not getting any results:

```
<c:forEach var='building' items='${WebAppContext.buildings}'>
  <p>${building.location.name}</p>
</c:forEach>
```

In the source of the page it just shows:

```
<c:forEach var='meeting' items='[Lorg.foo.bar.baz.bat.serviceapi.webserviceobject.xsd.BuildingsWSO;@3823ff8'>
  <p></p>
</c:forEach>
```

I'll admit that, not knowing anything about Java Expression Language, I don't understand why the items='' gets translated like it does though I can see that it follows a path in the setup we use.
Now when I use:

```
<p>${WebAppContext.buildings[0].location.name}</p>
<p>${WebAppContext.buildings[1].location.name}</p>
```

I get:

```
<p>Krustylu Studios</p>
<p>Springfield Nuclear Power Plant</p>
```

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnake.html

Comment: Can you really not use taglibs like JSTL? You're working with JSP, right?

Comment: @BalusC: I just updated my question to show what I am getting when I try the forEach suggestion offered below.

Comment: Did you install JSTL and declare the core taglib in top of JSP?

Comment: No I didn't... I will, though. Thanks for the replies. I never deal with Java in any way, shape or form so this is all uncharted territory for me (I had never even heard of something called JSTL before today).

Comment: Maybe it's time to learn JSP/Servlet by a book. *Head First Servlets and JSP* or *Core Servlets and JSP* (always pick the most recent edition!) is recommendable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that kind of advanced functionality is supported by EL; you can try using the JSTL c:forEach tag to iterate over your list.

Comment: Ugh. OK, looks like it won't be usable... I'll insist on getting the data in a format I can work with like JSON.

Comment: @gaoshan88 if you can use JSTL/EL on the page, you can definitely use the `<c:forEach>` construct.

Answer (score 3):

If you're seeing `<c:forEach var='meeting' items='[Lorg.foo.bar.baz.bat.serviceapi.webserviceobject.xsd.BuildingsWSO;@3823ff8'>` when you view page source from your browser, that implies that the `<c:forEach>` tag isn't being processed.

Make sure you've declared the tag library in the JSP page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

The `prefix="c"` is where you get the `c:` part of `<c:forEach>` ... if you were to say `prefix="foo"` the tag would then be `<foo:forEach>`

Answer (score 2):

This should be possible:

```
<c:forEach var='building' items='${WebAppContext.buildings}'>
  <p>${building.location.name}</p>
</c:forEach>
```

Now, how will you check to see whether `WebAppContext.buildings` is actually an array?  There's no direct easy way to do that with JSTL *unless* you have the power and ability to extend a local custom suite of EL functions to use from JSTL.

Comment: Look at @Stephen P's answer - you're page is not pulling in the standard tag library

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to know if an object is an array, you could create a custom JSP function.

```
public static boolean isArray(final Object o) {
    return o instanceof Object[];
}
```

Then just map it in a TLD such as:

```
<function>
    <description>
        Checks if the supplied object is an array.
    </description>
    <name>isArray</name>
    <function-class>com.example.JspFunctions</function-class>
    <function-signature>boolean isArray(java.lang.Object)</function-signature>
    <example>
        ${f:isArray(someVar)}
    </example>
</function>
```